# Unable to save data into Foreign key fields in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm working on a project where I have to enroll students in a course. I have a model called Enrollment with two foreign key fields to Course, and Student. I'm trying to save course and student in Enrollment model when they submit. But after calling the save method also response returns a response as course and student are required.

My models

````
class Course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=300,default=None)
    author = models.ForeignKey(TeacherProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,default=None)
    course_description = models.TextField(null=True)
    course_cover = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='course_covers/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name```

class Enrollment(models.Model):
    enroll_key = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="Text here",null=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course.course_name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['course','student']]
````

Serializer

```
class CourseEnrollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Enrollment
        fields = ['enroll_key','course','student']
```

My views

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def EnrollCourse(request,pk):
    course = Course.objects.get(id=pk)
    print("course",course)
    student = StudentProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    print("student",student)
    serializer = CourseEnrollSerializer(data=request.data)
    print(serializer)
    print("loading the serializer...")
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(course=course,student=student)
    else:
        print("Serializer not valid",serializer.errors)
    return Response(serializer.errors)

urls.py

path('enrollcourse/<int:pk>/',views.EnrollCourse,name='enroll_course'),
#pk is course primarykey

What I get after printing serializer.errors

{'course': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'student': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. the error you are getting might be because of unique together in your model meta, I tried using your code and got the same error when an enrollment for the course and student already exists. deleted the enrollment of the user and it worked.

so you are trying to save enrollment with same user and course that's why you are getting this error.

2. you are validating the serializer with

> request.data

make sure you are providing data in this, then you are setting student and course when you are saving the data.
before **serializer.save()** your serializer gets invalid because there is no data in request.data or invalid data.
i have checked it by providing course and student in POST method and it is working fine.

suggestions:
POST course, student in request as they are required fields and just simply do request.save().